# PHP exec Failing with Status = 3

Tags: php

I have the following code snippet:

```
$app = '"' . getcwd() . "\\prog.exe" . '"';
exec("$app param1 param2", $output, $status);
```

It runs fine locally on EasyPHP-12.1, but when I uploaded it to the deployment server, it failed with $status==3.  I tried leaving out the path like so:

```
exec("prog.exe param1 param2", $output, $status)
```

Again, it ran fine locally, but failed on the server.

Can you think of anything that I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Ask the program you are calling. Its documentation should give you more info about what status 3 means. Also, the return value of `exec()` may contain an error message.

Comment: Actually, I wrote the program it's calling and I'm not returning a status.  It's a windows executable that runs in console mode, and according to the windows return code, 3 means path not found.  I wonder if it's a path mapping issue?

Comment: I would check to see if it is a permissions issue.  If it works on one server, but not on another, that could be an issue.

Comment: It may be.  I contacted the hosting provider and they said they disabled executables for security reasons!  They were supposed to enable it, but now I'm getting a different error.  I'm working on it with them right now.  Thanks for all the help folks!